# How to Implement Spring Security in Grails Graphql in Grail 4.x

Tags: grails, spring-security, graphql

How to Implement role in View in Grails Graphql

class Career {
String name
String description
Integer positions

```
static graphql = GraphQLMapping.build {

    query('careerByName',Career){
     dataFetcher(new DataFetcher() {
         @Override
         Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) throws Exception {
             return Career.findByName(environment.getArgument('name'))
         }
     })
    }
}

static constraints = {




}
static mapping = {

}
```

}

class Career {
String name
String description
Integer positions

```
static graphql = GraphQLMapping.build {

    query('careerByName',Career){
     dataFetcher(new DataFetcher() {
         @Override
         Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) throws Exception {
             return Career.findByName(environment.getArgument('name'))
         }
     })
    }
}

static constraints = {




}
static mapping = {

}
```

}